# Eclipse Crashes (Not Responding) while "populate auto detected configs"

Tags: eclipse, spring

My Eclipse crashes while trying to load and the last process is "populate auto detected configs".

Comment: Can you cancel the process?

Comment: no it just crashes I have restarted my pc and tried to run Eclipse -clean in command prompt and nothing worked

Comment: Try to load eclipse with `-clearPersistedState` option.

Comment: it worked! can you please explain?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. It was just trial and error ;) Glad it worked.

Comment: I suspect this comes from the Spring Tool Suite (STS). My eclipse keeps crashing since I installed it. Will remove it and see if it helps...

Comment: @Leistungsabfall should submit it as an answer so it NotANumber can accept it.  I had the same problem when STS tried to update itself and "populate auto detected configs" was never completing, preventing startup (but no crashing).  clearPersistedState fixed it.

Comment: @Leistungsabfall How do you load it with '-clearPersistedState' option.. Eclipse is not getting started only..

Comment: I am facing this problem on starting up eclipse, it doesn't start

Comment: I faced the same problem with STS, I ended up by deleted my workspace, and recreating a fresh one ;(

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue and I've resolved disabling auto config in Spring plugin.

In Eclipse, open: `Windows > Preferences > Spring > Bean Supports`
Check the option `Disable Auto Config Detection`.

Answer (score 3):

Leistungsabfall's solution worked for me:

> Try to load eclipse with -clearPersistedState option.

Comment: Did work temporally for me. But didn't solve the problem. Besides, allot of my settings were gone. Views, etc. ...